# How to call javascript function on checkboxlist item selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net

HTML :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1"  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>C++</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ASP.Net</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Javascript</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>CSS</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>HTML</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Java</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<div id="idskill">
    <asp:Label  ID="lblskilldescription" runat="server">Description</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbskilldescription" runat="server" Width="150px" OnTextChanged="TextBox8_TextChanged" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Scripts :

```
function toggleDiv()
  {       
      $("#idskill").slideToggle("slow");
      return false;
  }
```

What I want is on selection `Other` div should toggle, on uncheck it should hide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563184/javascript-asp-net-manage-checkboxlist

Answer (score 1):

There should be "onchange" listener for the element. At least using JS we use the onchange event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this might help.

```
function list_onclick() {
        var list = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');
        var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked && inputs[i].value == "1") {
               //do your work
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how this function will get called automatically when selection is made..?